# Facing issue while running Testcases from runner class in the Cucumber with ObjectFactory with Latest Version of Cucumber

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: Could not find object factory org.example.CustomObjectFactory.

Cucumber uses SPI to discover object factory implementations.
Has the class been registered with SPI and is it available on
the classpath?

```
at io.cucumber.core.runtime.ObjectFactoryServiceLoader.loadSelectedObjectFactory(ObjectFactoryServiceLoader.java:93)
at io.cucumber.core.runtime.ObjectFactoryServiceLoader.loadObjectFactory(ObjectFactoryServiceLoader.java:46)
at java.base/java.lang.ThreadLocal$SuppliedThreadLocal.initialValue(ThreadLocal.java:305)
at java.base/java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:195)
at java.base/java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:172)
at io.cucumber.core.runtime.ThreadLocalObjectFactorySupplier.get(ThreadLocalObjectFactorySupplier.java:18)
at io.cucumber.core.runtime.BackendServiceLoader.loadBackends(BackendServiceLoader.java:48)
at io.cucumber.core.runtime.BackendServiceLoader.get(BackendServiceLoader.java:37)
at io.cucumber.core.runtime.BackendServiceLoader.get(BackendServiceLoader.java:33)
at io.cucumber.core.runtime.ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier.createRunner(ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier.java:46)
at java.base/java.lang.ThreadLocal$SuppliedThreadLocal.initialValue(ThreadLocal.java:305)
at java.base/java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:195)
at java.base/java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:172)
at io.cucumber.core.runtime.ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier.get(ThreadLocalRunnerSupplier.java:40)
at io.cucumber.core.runtime.RethrowingThrowableCollector.executeAndThrow(RethrowingThrowableCollector.java:35)
at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.getRunner(CucumberExecutionContext.java:140)
at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runBeforeAllHooks(CucumberExecutionContext.java:92)
at io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberRunner.<init>(TestNGCucumberRunner.java:124)
at io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.setUpClass(AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.java:27)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:69)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:393)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:326)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:180)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:122)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:819)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:619)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:443)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:437)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:397)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:336)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1228)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1134)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1101)
at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:65)
at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:105)
```

Ideally, It should work with Latest version of Cucumber but it's throwing above error but the same code is working cucumber 3.x.x version without any changes.

Let me know any changes happend in the cucumber latest version

Comment: Are you using an executable jar? If so you have to merge the files in `META-INF/services` correctly using either https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/using-container-descriptor-handlers.html or https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#ServicesResourceTransformer

Comment: You aren't using an executable jar, please read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html#introduction to understand the error message.

Comment: Do you have a `META-INF/services` folder in your project?

Comment: I have added Meta-INF/services folder and also added cucumber.properties file also but the start() method is not calling from CustomObjectFactory Class

Comment: The above issue has been resolved but the CustomObjectFactory class is not working with JDK 17 and cucumber 7 and not able to load the environment variables

Comment: Please read the oracle docs I linked earlier, you should not only create `META-INF/services` but put the right files with the right content in there.